# Hyperledger anchor peers cannot communicate with each other because of tls bad certificate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I had created a hyperledger fabric channel **[channel1]** with two peer organizations**(Org1,Org2)** and one orderer organization **(OrdererOrg)**, and there are one peer **(peer0.org1.com/peer0.org2.com)** in each peer organization and three orderer nodes**[Orderer0, Orderer1, Orderer 2]** in the orderer organization. After joining ordering nodes and peers into the channel and setting [peer0.org1.com] and [peer0.org2.com] as anchor peers, the follow errors are printed in peer logs:

> peer0.org1.com

```
2021-04-14 10:53:08.108 CST [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 1a2 Server TLS handshake failed in 962.117µs with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:58281
2021-04-14 10:53:09.112 CST [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 1a3 Server TLS handshake failed in 2.162124ms with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remoteaddress=127.0.0.1:58283
2021-04-14 10:53:10.836 CST [core.comm] ServerHandshake -> ERRO 1a4 Server TLS handshake failed in 1.629684ms with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer remote address=127.0.0.1:58285
```

> peer0.org2.com

```
2021-04-14 10:53:11.107 CST [gossip.gossip] func1 -> WARN 12f Deep probe of localhost:20000 for channel channel1 failed: context deadline exceeded
2021-04-14 10:53:11.108 CST [gossip.discovery] func1 -> WARN 130 Could not connect to Endpoint: localhost:20000, InternalEndpoint: localhost:20000, PKI-ID: <nil>, Metadata:  : context deadline exceeded
```

[**configtx.yaml**](https://github.com/yw-scu/hyperledger-fabric-anchor-error/blob/main/configtx.yaml)

[**core.yaml of [peer0.org1.com]**](https://github.com/yw-scu/hyperledger-fabric-anchor-error/blob/main/core-org1.yaml)

[**core.yaml of [peer0.org2.com]**](https://github.com/yw-scu/hyperledger-fabric-anchor-error/blob/main/core-org2.yaml)

The tutorials I followed:

[Creating a channel](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/create_channel/create_channel_participation.html)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by add an folder named tlscacerts to the organization msp.
Noticed that in the test-network */test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/msp/tlscacerts/*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Led5R.png)
copy your tls root ca certificate into it.